# how to make two buttons print different section using windows.print?

Tags: jquery, css, printing

Let's saying I have two buttons like `Print1`, `Print2`. Each button should print each section having Id of `id='print1'`, `id='print2'`. How do I achieve that? I have `@media print` to style the whole page but how do I separate the section depending on the button I click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function printContent(el){
  var restorepage = $('body').html();
  var printcontent = $('#' + el).clone();
  $('body').empty().html(printcontent);
  window.print();
  $('body').html(restorepage);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button onclick="printContent('print-1');">Print [1]</button>
  <button onclick="printContent('print-2');">Print [2]</button>
</div>

<br>

<div id="print-1">
  <h1>[Print 1] What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
  <p>
  <b>Lorem Ipsum</b> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
  </p>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="print-2">
  <h1>[Print 2] Where does it come from?</h1>
  <p>
  <b>Contrary</b> to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word
  </p>
</div>
```